# Trying to get jQuery UI AutoComplete to Work with Tags Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a tagging plugin for jQuery that I've installed, and I want to couple it with jQuery UI's autocomplete.

Both of the two plugins work fine independant of each other, but I am having trouble getting them to work together. I've enclosed a sample at a jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/ecbjG/

If you scroll to the bottom, you can comment out either of the two plugins and the other works fine. But with the tagging plugin enabled, the autocomplete does not function.

I was hoping someone could show me where I am making my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tagging plugin will replace your text input with the id **tags** with an input control that has the id **tags_tag**.

So after you bind the tagging plugin to the input control you have to bind the autocomplete plugin to **tags_tag**.

```
$('#tags').tagsInput();

$("#tags_tag").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // something will happen eventually ...
    }
});
```

**update**
The problem is that the tagging plug-in will add the tag if the input is losing focus (blur event). This event is fired before the autocomplete plugin can set the value of the input. Therefore the plugin takes the currently entered value (e.g. Pyt) and adds it as a tag instead of the selected value (e.g. Python). I have removed the blur event and triggered and keypress (simulating "Enter") to make this work, but this is totally a hack :) ...

Maybe you want to study the tagging plug-in more deeply. I have seen it has a setting for autocomplete.

```
var settings = jQuery.extend({
    ...
    autocomplete: {
        selectFirst: false
    },
    ...
}, options);
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/ecbjG/5/ (updated)

Comment: Hrnm. That does work, somewhat, but it just appends a new tag instead of the current one.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not entirely sure what you mean. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Well, if you start typing, then pick an option from the dropdown list, you get the text you started typing as a tag, then the text you selected as another tag - instead of just the text you selected as a tag.

Comment: Updated the answer for you sir.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have made it more clear that my experience with Javascript is extremely poor. Thank you for clarifying for me. I appreciate the detailed information.